# I need to two functions assign to one button in tkinter first click to do edit function second time click to save function called

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button

[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ltWU.jpg)

As seen in the screenshot, I need one button for two functions in tkinter Python.

The edit button is clicked to activate some action same time change button text saves.
Save is the same as the edit button is clicked to save data but one button changes text and function.

The first click is to do the first function.
The next click is for saving the function, not one click cannot do the same function.

Comment: Okay now that you have specified your need, what do you need help with? Or where are you facing your problems? Also note that, stackoverflow is not a writecodeforyou site

Comment: It is hard to understand what your question is without punctuations.

Comment: Simply bind a function to `command` option and in that function performs corresponding task based on the text of the button.  Then change the text of the button before exiting the function.